# Read mp3 file from Remote URL in Nodejs

Tags: node.js, file, npm, buffer, fs

I am trying to read a remote MP3 file from the URL 
https://rmlcerts.blob.core.windows.net/certificates/sample%20podcast%20(mp3cut.net).mp3?sp=r&st=2020-05-21T09:51:17Z&se=2020-05-21T17:51:17Z&spr=https&sv=2019-10-10&sr=b&sig=By69Tw45FXQuGTx7Dq9%2F2Qo5sDxwjLo4dR9nl61ocCU%3D

The URL sends out an `application/octet-stream` but the content-type in the response turns out to be audio/mpeg. I need to save the file to local storage or convert directly into base64 streams.

I have referred to endless tutorials but all in vain.

What is the best way to get base64 from the remote audio file using NodeJS?

Here is what I tried so far:

```
request.get(audioUrl, function (error, response, audioBody) {
        if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
            console.log('Received audio');
            console.log(response.headers);
            var uniqueId= uuidv4();
            console.log(uniqueId);
            var file = fs.createWriteStream(uniqueId+'.rml');
            file.write(audioBody);
    }
})
```

I also tried below conversion to base64 directly:

```
request.get(audioUrl, function (error, response, audioBody) {
        if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
                const data = Buffer.from(audioBody,'binary').toString('base64');    
        }
})
```

None of these work which sounds strange to me.